# FileInterceptor doesn't work

Tags: javascript, nestjs

What am I doing wrong?

```
@Post('upload')
@UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
    async upload( @UploadedFile() file) {
      console.log(file)
    }
```

file is `undefined`

[image: postman]

Comment: Can you verify that `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` exists in the request header?

Comment: i added `multipart/form-data;boundary`, but still `file` is `undefined`

Comment: I've copied your code and tested it. It works for me. Have you tried the usual? For example deleting `node_modules` and `npm install`. Are your dependencies up to date? (try `npm outdated`) This is what I get for an empty file: `{ fieldname: 'file',
  originalname: 'file',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'application/octet-stream',
  buffer: [],
  size: 0 }`

Comment: thanks for your reply, I deleted the `node_modules` and now everything worked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code works as expected in a fresh project. Hence, the dependencies are corrupt. Deleting the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same issue, but the file mentioned in the body wasn't actually present. I had deleted the file and that postman request was an old one. try selecting a  new file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).